# SDL Tridion 2011 content manager - date filter is missing on list view

Tags: firefox, tridion, tridion-2011

The filter by date button from the top of the list view panel has disappeared. This happened a couple of months ago for a colleague, and just now for me. Other users here don't have this problem. I can still filter by Name, Type and From Publication but where Date used to be is blanked out.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ1uu.jpg).

Sorry if this is a really stupid question but I can't for the life of me find a setting for this or any one else with the same problem.

This is in Firefox 33.0, Chrome and IE both have (many) other issues on our system and can't be used.

Comment: Are you using Chrome?  It's notorious for having issues with the Tridion CME.  Did you try other browsers?

Comment: Should have said: this is in Firefox 33.0. Chrome and IE are buggy or don't work at all on our setup.

Comment: IE shouldn't be buggy - just slow.  I've noticed this issue with FF as well.  Unfortunately I don't have an answer.  My suggestion is to submit a Support ticket with SDL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Tridion, but not about programming. It should be on http://tridion.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looked into this issue here.

In our case it happens when the view is set to a value other than 100%.

Below or above this the "Modified date" column header vanishes, above this the advanced search button also vanishes.

I hope this fixes it for you!

Andy

Comment: When you say "the view is set", do you mean the zoom level?

Comment: Great! had a customer who kept having the same issue. Unknowingly she kept changing her zoom level :-D

Answer (score 0):

Click right mouse button in the title bar of the missing filter. Choose 'This frame' and then 'Reload frame'. That worked for me.

Regards.